# Bash float calculation issue

Tags: bash, unix, decimal

I've tried many different ways of evaluating the mess below as a float. I think I'm almost there with the use of bc but it's still not evaluating.

```
s=$((($s+((${flowx[$(($a+1))]}-(${flowx[$a]}))*(${flowy[$(($a+1))]}+${flowy[$a]}))/2) | bc))
```

Any input?

Comment: BashFAQ #22 is your friend -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022 -- but it tells you to only use `bc`, which... well, yeah. Use `bc`, don't use `$(( ))`. Since you already know that `bc` exists, and that it can do floating-point math, how is this a question?

Comment: Can you provide an example of numbers you're running through that thing? What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: Hsve you considered using awk/perl/python/ruby?

Comment: @dawg, pah; `dc` gives you true arbitrary-precision math rather than the compromises inherent in IEEE floating-point. It's actually _more accurate_ (if asked to be) than what awk/perl/python/ruby/etc. do out-of-the-box with floats.

Comment: Of course you are correct. Just seems a lot of work to get there ;-)

Comment: flowx and flowy are two arrays which will be inserted with csv's read by the program earlier on. The data reading doesn't seem to be a problem but here are some examples of the types of elements in the array:

0.124852 -0.0156593
-0.0932662 -0.0464323
0.0305706 0.00833429
0.0245359 0.0292034
-0.0564935 0.197532
0.120311 0.0864692
-0.0071995 0.097294
0.0624036 0.0825287
0 0.0340206

Comment: @JoshuaJenkins, it's not about thinking there's a problem with the reading, it's about being able to test. If you give us values (not just an "example", but an actual runnable value) for `flowx`, `flowy`, and `s`, and then tell us what the next value for `s` you *expect* is, then we can actually test our answers. See also http://sscce.org/ or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid all quotes and such things if you instead of the `hereline` (as @CharlesDuffy in the otherwise great answer recommends) will use the `heredoc` as like:

```
flowx=(0.124852 -0.0156593 -0.0932662 -0.0464323 0.0305706 0.00833429 0.0245359 0.0292034 -0.0564935)
flowy=(0.197532 0.120311 0.0864692 -0.0071995 0.097294 0.0624036 0.0825287 0 0.0340206)
a=1
s=0.1

res=$(bc -l <<EOF
$s + ( ( ${flowx[a+1]} - ${flowx[a]} ) * ( ${flowy[a+1]} + ${flowy[a]} ) ) / 2
EOF
)
echo "$res"
```

prints

```
.09197621484831000000
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks guys for all your help. I'm relatively new to all of this so my apologies for my lack of information. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `$(( ))` at all.

For instance, taking a relevant part of your calculation:

```
s=$(bc <<<"$s + ( ( ${flowx[a+1]} - ${flowx[a]} ) * ( ${flowy[a+1]} + ${flowy[a]} ) ) / 2")
```

As long as `flowx` and `flowy` are standard integer-indexed arrays rather than associative arrays, you don't even need to use `$(( ))` when indexing into them (or `$` operators inside those indices), as the index of a nonassociative array in bash is a math context by default.

Or, more readably than all these nested parens, use `dc` (here, configured with 10 digits of precision):

```
s=$(dc <<EOF
10 k
${flowx[a+1]}
${flowx[a]}
-
${flowy[a+1]}
${flowy[a]}
+
*
$s +
2 /
p
EOF
)
```

See? **Much** more readable.

Comment: My arrays are standard integer-indexed. Using what you wrote, it gave me this error: (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Do you know what that could be from?

Comment: First, `<<<` is a bashism -- if you're using `/bin/sh` rather than bash, there's potential for an error there. Beyond that, change the `bc <<<` to an `echo` and hand-check the expansion -- this is off-the-cuff rather than something that could be tested, since you didn't provide samples of your arrays' values &c. sufficient to _allow_ testing of any proposed solution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy change  the `flowax` to `flowx` in the `bc` line... ;)

Comment: I updated the echo and the flowx (I feel so retarded about that one...) and now it's giving me this error:

File echo0 + ( ( -0.0231005 - -0.0217739 ) * ( 0.0478359 + 0.0478459 ) ) / 2 is unavailable. Those numbers are the kinds of numbers that I'm dealing with

Comment: @JoshuaJenkins, did you write `<<<`, *exactly* as given? If you wrote, say, `<"..."` rather than `<<<"..."`, that would do what you described. (Even if that guess is incorrect, it'd be helpful if you provided a copy-and-paste of the invocation).

Comment: ...I've double-checked the answer here, and while I'm not confident that I read and transcribed your formula correctly, I _am_ confident that I transcribed the quoting and other bash syntax correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If ksh93 is installed on your system, I suggest you use it instead of bash for this task.  It has built-in support for 64 bit IEEE floating point.